# How can a Controller in a Codeigniter project be correctly routed without an entry in routes.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am working on a Codeigniter project where there are several controllers: Manufacturers, Results, and Edit.  I was having an issue with the Manufacturers controller so I opened up routes.php.  I found this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "results";
$route['404_override'] = '404.html';
```

There were no entries for Manufacturers or Edit.  However, I can view pages created by the Edit controller by navigating to the appropriate urls.  It appears that Codeigniter can find Edit, but not Manufacturers.  This is strange to me, because neither appear in the routes.php file.  Can Codeigniter correct this automatically?  Are there other explanations for how this is working (or not working?)

Edit: it sounds like the problems I am having with this page and not related to a routing issue, but some other issue.

Edit: I looked at the php log file and found an issue with the database configuration.  The Edit controller does not load that database, so that's why Edit is able to run correctly.  To fix the problem, i needed to change the database driver from mysql to mysqli.

Comment: [That's how CodeIgniter works.](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html) You only need routes for super special occasions.

Comment: What you're describing is intended behavior by CI. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Answer (score 1):

route looks like an alias to a controller. for example: $route['forgot-password'] = 'forgotpassword'; forgotpassword is a controller, but if forgot-password is typed, forgotpassword page still can be opened.